# The time difference in Java

Tags: java, android, time

I'm looking for some solution which will be faster than mine. I get a time difference between current time and my saved, next step is to put the time in TextView. This solution works but it makes my app very slowly. Does anyone know faster solution?

```
Thread counter = new Thread(){
                    public void run()
                    {

                    long saved
                    long difference;
                        while(true)
                        {
                        saved = Long.parseLong(getString(c, "0", "saved"));// sharedPreferences

                        difference = System.currentTimeMillis() - saved;                                


                        seconds = (int) (difference / 1000) % 60;   
                        difference-=seconds;
                        minutes= (int)((difference/ 60000 ) % 60);
                        difference=minutes;
                        hours = (int) ((difference/ 3600000) % 24);
                        days = (int) ((difference/86400000) % 30);
                        difference-=days;
                        months= (int) ((difference/2592000)/1000);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                             @Override
                             public void run() {

                                 myTextView5.setText(Integer.toString(seconds));    
                                 myTextView4.setText(Integer.toString(minutes));
                                 myTextView3.setText(Integer.toString(hours));
                                 myTextView2.setText(Integer.toString(days));
                                 myTextView1.setText(Integer.toString(months));

                            }

                        });
```

Comment: put some sleep instead of while(true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your precision is 1s - so you can Thread.sleep (1000) in the while without missing a beat.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding you are using runOnUiThread that created temporary shortlife objects that is the main reason your code is running slow because in each iteration it does it created a new instance of Runnable class and then updates your UI.

Read this topic to get a good understanding of Communication with Ui Thread

http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

You can use Handlers to overcome this issue all you need to do is pass message to handler and it will do the job for you.

This is how you do it.

First of all create a custom handler class

```
public class CustomMessageHandler extends Handler {

private IUpdateAudioProgressListView iUpdateRef;

public void setOnProgressUpdatedListner(IUpdateAudioProgressListView ref) {
    this.iUpdateRef = ref;
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.handleMessage(msg);



     YOUR HANDLING CODE HERE ......................

}

}
```

then in order to send message to UI thread from a custom thread you need to do following things

initialize a class level variable in your thread class like

```
public class Test {

CustomMessageHandler handler;

public Test() {
    handler = new CustomMessageHandler();


    Thread counter = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            long saved
            long difference;
            while (true) {
                saved = Long.parseLong(getString(c, "0", "saved"));// sharedPreferences

                difference = System.currentTimeMillis() - saved;


                seconds = (int) (difference / 1000) % 60;
                difference -= seconds;
                minutes = (int) ((difference / 60000) % 60);
                difference = minutes;
                hours = (int) ((difference / 3600000) % 24);
                days = (int) ((difference / 86400000) % 30);
                difference -= days;
                months = (int) ((difference / 2592000) / 1000);

                Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                msg.obj = // send all your variables via a class or whatever logic you use
                        handler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    };
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the use of [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

```
DateTime saved = //getSaved;
DateTime diff = DateTime.now().minus(saved);

//update TextView

txtView.setText(diff.getSecondsOfMinute().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an external library, I would suggest the use of java.util.Calendar (Don't forget to import that!). For your solution, every time your value in SharedPreferences is changed, just run the code below.

Code to calc diff

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(difference);
int months = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); 
int days = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

myTextView5.setText(Integer.toString(seconds));    
myTextView4.setText(Integer.toString(minutes));
myTextView3.setText(Integer.toString(hours));
myTextView2.setText(Integer.toString(days));
myTextView1.setText(Integer.toString(months));
```

Detect change in preferences

```
public class MyPreferences extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        // handle the preference change here
    }
}
```